# how to pass a variable from Octave to c?

Tags: c, math, octave

In the following program calculates the determinant in c via Octave. But i don´t know how to pass the variable from octave to c:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{ 
    FILE *graf;
    graf=popen("octave -persist","w");
    if (graf==NULL){
        printf("Error \n");}
    else
    { 
        int a;
 printf("input the dimension: \n");
 scanf("%d",&a);
 fprintf(graf,"N= %d;",a);
 fprintf(graf,"pkg load statistics \n");
 fprintf(graf,"M=N-1;");
 fprintf(graf," for i=1:%d \n",a);
 fprintf(graf," for j=1:%d \n",a);
 fprintf(graf," matriz(i,j)=round(1+9*rand());");
 fprintf(graf," endfor \n");
 fprintf(graf,"endfor \n");
 fprintf(graf,"C = combnk(1:%d,M);",a);
 fprintf(graf,"Combinaciones=size(C,1);");
 fprintf(graf,"for i=1:Combinaciones \n");
 fprintf(graf,"for j=1:Combinaciones \n");
 fprintf(graf,"for h=1:M \n");
 fprintf(graf,"for k=1:M \n");
 fprintf(graf,"matrices(h,k)=matriz(C(i,h),C(j,k));");
 fprintf(graf,"endfor \n");
 fprintf(graf,"endfor \n");
 fprintf(graf,"nuevamatriz(Combinaciones-i+1,Combinaciones-j+1)=det(matrices);");
 fprintf(graf,"endfor \n");
 fprintf(graf,"endfor \n");
 fprintf(graf,"matriz \n");
 fprintf(graf,"det(matriz) \n");
 fprintf(graf,"nuevamatriz \n");
 fprintf(graf,"det(nuevamatriz) \n");
pclose(graf);
    }
printf("Have that the second determinant (attached matrix) is always the first (matrix) powered at dimension less one \n\n ");
}
```

A way to define this determining variable in c.

Comment: I' ḿ sorry.The second line has to be deleted.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to update it.

Comment: @Luis Federico Berruezo Sánchez – 
Why do you use `-persist`?

Comment: You interfacing with octave using stdio/stdout so you want to send a print variable command to octave.  It looks like  Alternative check out the external code interface particular the (legacy?) mex files as you are using C.

Comment: thank you all.  But you can see that  i send the variable to octave. What i don't know is receiving.

Comment: perhaps if the pipe is read-write rather than just write, and then you attempt to print from octave to stdout and then use your pipe to read from it? It "will" be just text though, not numerical. I agree with Allan, use the Mex interface if you want to perform octave operations within a c context.

Comment: @Luis Federico Berruezo Sánchez – Your edit doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

First: I use `-persist` because it's the same via to call gnuplot.
Second: It motivated me to use this method was It calculating the determinant of any matrix without do so much Code. But I have solved It embedding Python in c with the header `< Python.h>` and compiling It like this:  `gcc -I/usr/include/python3.11/ program.c -lpython3.11. -o program`
since Python include the module numpy and It's more easy even than with octave.
Thank you and here, an example:

```
`

#include <Python.h>
     int main() {
char a[27]="[[1,2,3],[90,23,3],[1,5,7]]";
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import numpy as np");
PyRun_SimpleString("det=np.linalg.det([[1,2,3],[90,23,3],
[1,5,7]])");
PyRun_SimpleString("print('the determinant is:',det)");
Py_Finalize();
return 0;
}`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can do exactly the same thing with Octave, see linked duplicate or the [documentation](https://docs.octave.org/v8.2.0/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs).

Answer (score 0):

it can also be done as follows,so the variable is stored in a file and then it can be recovered. This program reads an square matrix like a list of numbers starting with a number that is the dimension from a file, after save the determinant in another file. I use it to compare matrices and determinants.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void enteroACadena(int numero, char *bufer);
int main(void)
{
char file[10];
printf("Enter the name of the file: \n");
scanf("%s",file);
FILE *fp;
 FILE *graf;
 graf=popen("octave","w");
 fprintf(graf,"clear; \n");
int buffer[50][50];
int g;
fp = fopen ( file, "r" );
fscanf(fp, "%d", &g);
for(int r1=1;r1<g+1;r1++)
{
for(int r2=1;r2<g+1;r2++)
{
fscanf(fp, "%d" ,&buffer[r1][r2]);
char cadena[11]; // 
    char cadena1[3];
    char cadena2[3];
    enteroACadena(buffer[r1][r2], cadena);
    enteroACadena(r1, cadena1);
    enteroACadena(r2, cadena2);
fprintf(graf,"matriz(%s,%s)=%s;\n",cadena1,cadena2,cadena);
//printf("matriz(%s,%s)=%s;  ",cadena1,cadena2,cadena);
}
    printf("\n");
    }

 fprintf(graf,"d=det(matriz) \n");
 fprintf(graf,"save %s.det d \n",file);
pclose(graf);

fclose ( fp );

return 0;
}
void enteroACadena(int numero, char *bufer){

    sprintf(bufer, "%d", numero);
}
```